# Is Firmware Boot Manager critical? Or can it be deleted if you have Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, efi, bootmgr

I would like to reset {fwbootmgr} because it not linking to {bootmgr} even though in display order

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier                 {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                            {9090be8e-4d7c-11e3-b2e3-08606e0fb7bc}
timeout                 0
```

only way i can think of resetting it is to delete it

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: @ElipticalView win7x64 and win8x64 with  EUFI safeboot disabled and enabled CSM if it makes a difference

Comment: Thanks. This is over my head, but it was interesting to read about EUFI and CSM which I was unaware of.